# SOAPpy installation unable to find fpconst eventhough its installed

Tags: python, soappy

I am a complete novice to the python world and have recently been asked to migrate a legacy application that runs on Python 2.4.15, SOAPpy Module & fpconst.

While installing SOAPpy 0.12.4 on the machine, I get an error saying that its unable to locate fpconst eventhough it has been installed on the server.

PFB the steps followed

1. Installed Python 2.4.15
2. Installed setuptools-0.6c11.win32-py2.4.exe
3. Installed wstools-0.3
4. installed fpconst-0.7.2

> > > import fpconst
> > >       fpconst.**version**
> > >       '0.7.2'

1. Tried to install SOAPpy 0.12.4 but receiving an error saying

Installed d:\python2.4\lib\site-packages\soappy-0.12.4-py2.4.egg
Processing dependencies for SOAPpy==0.12.4
Searching for fpconst
Reading _http://pypi.python.org/simple/fpconst/
Download error: (11001, 'getaddrinfo failed') -- Some packages may not be found!

Couldn't find index page for 'fpconst' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading _http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error: (11001, 'getaddrinfo failed') -- Some packages may not be found!

PFB the complete installation log :

> D:\Temp\SOAPpy
>   trial\SOAPpy-0.12.4>python setup.py
>   build running build running build_py
>   creating build creating build\lib
>   creating build\lib\SOAPpy copying
>   src\SOAPpy\Client.py ->
>   build\lib\SOAPpy copying
>   src\SOAPpy\Config.py ->
>   build\lib\SOAPpy copying
>   src\SOAPpy\Errors.py ->
>   build\lib\SOAPpy copying
>   src\SOAPpy\GSIServer.py ->
>   build\lib\SOAPpy copying
>   src\SOAPpy\NS.py -> build\lib\SOAPpy
>   copying src\SOAPpy\Parser.py ->
>   build\lib\SOAPpy copying
>   src\SOAPpy\Server.py ->
>   build\lib\SOAPpy copying
>   src\SOAPpy\SOAP.py -> build\lib\SOAPpy
>   copying src\SOAPpy\SOAPBuilder.py ->
>   build\lib\SOAPpy copying
>   src\SOAPpy\Types.py ->
>   build\lib\SOAPpy copying
>   src\SOAPpy\URLopener.py ->
>   build\lib\SOAPpy copying
>   src\SOAPpy\Utilities.py ->
>   build\lib\SOAPpy copying
>   src\SOAPpy\version.py ->
>   build\lib\SOAPpy copying
>   src\SOAPpy\WSDL.py -> build\lib\SOAPpy
>   copying src\SOAPpy__init__.py ->
>   build\lib\SOAPpy running egg_info
>   writing requirements to
>   src\SOAPpy.egg-info\requires.txt
>   writing src\SOAPpy.egg-info\PKG-INFO
>   writing top-level names to
>   src\SOAPpy.egg-info\top_level.txt
>   writing dependency_links to
>   src\SOAPpy.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
>   reading manifest file
>   'src\SOAPpy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
>   writing manifest file
>   'src\SOAPpy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
>
> D:\Temp\SOAPpy
>   trial\SOAPpy-0.12.4>python setup.py
>   install running install running
>   bdist_egg running egg_info writing
>   requirements to
>   src\SOAPpy.egg-info\requires.txt
>   writing src\SOAPpy.egg-info\PKG-INFO
>   writing top-level names to
>   src\SOAPpy.egg-info\top_level.txt
>   writing dependency_links to
>   src\SOAPpy.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
>   reading manifest file
>   'src\SOAPpy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
>   writing manifest file
>   'src\SOAPpy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
>   installing library code to
>   build\bdist.win32\egg running
>   install_lib running build_py creating
>   build\bdist.win32 creating
>   build\bdist.win32\egg creating
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy copying
>   build\lib\SOAPpy\Client.py ->
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy copying
>   build\lib\SOAPpy\Config.py ->
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy copying
>   build\lib\SOAPpy\Errors.py ->
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy copying
>   build\lib\SOAPpy\GSIServer.py ->
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy copying
>   build\lib\SOAPpy\NS.py ->
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy copying
>   build\lib\SOAPpy\Parser.py ->
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy copying
>   build\lib\SOAPpy\Server.py ->
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy copying
>   build\lib\SOAPpy\SOAP.py ->
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy copying
>   build\lib\SOAPpy\SOAPBuilder.py ->
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy copying
>   build\lib\SOAPpy\Types.py ->
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy copying
>   build\lib\SOAPpy\URLopener.py ->
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy copying
>   build\lib\SOAPpy\Utilities.py ->
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy copying
>   build\lib\SOAPpy\version.py ->
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy copying
>   build\lib\SOAPpy\WSDL.py ->
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy copying
>   build\lib\SOAPpy__init__.py ->
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy
>   byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy\Client.py
>   to Client.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy\Config.py
>   to Config.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy\Errors.py
>   to Errors.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy\GSIServer.py
>   to GSIServer.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy\NS.py to
>   NS.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy\Parser.py
>   to Parser.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy\Server.py
>   to Server.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy\SOAP.py
>   to SOAP.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy\SOAPBuilder.py
>   to SOAPBuilder.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy\Types.py
>   to Types.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy\URLopener.py
>   to URLopener.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy\Utilities.py
>   to Utilities.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy\version.py
>   to version.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy\WSDL.py
>   to WSDL.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy__init__.py
>   to **init**.pyc creating
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO copying
>   src\SOAPpy.egg-info\PKG-INFO ->
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO copying
>   src\SOAPpy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt ->
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO copying
>   src\SOAPpy.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
>   -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-IN FO copying
>   src\SOAPpy.egg-info\requires.txt ->
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO copying
>   src\SOAPpy.egg-info\top_level.txt ->
>   build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
>   zip_safe flag not set; analyzing
>   archive contents... creating dist
>   creating
>   'dist\SOAPpy-0.12.4-py2.4.egg' and
>   adding 'build\bdist.win32\egg' to it
>
> removing 'build\bdist.win32\egg' (and
>   everything under it) Processing
>   SOAPpy-0.12.4-py2.4.egg Copying
>   SOAPpy-0.12.4-py2.4.egg to
>   d:\python2.4\lib\site-packages Adding
>   SOAPpy 0.12.4 to easy-install.pth file
>
> Installed
>   d:\python2.4\lib\site-packages\soappy-0.12.4-py2.4.egg
>   Processing dependencies for
>   SOAPpy==0.12.4 Searching for fpconst
>   Reading
>   http://pypi.python.org/simple/fpconst/
>   Download error: (11001, 'getaddrinfo
>   failed') -- Some packages may not be
>   found!
>
> Couldn't find index page for 'fpconst'
>   (maybe misspelled?) Scanning index of
>   all packages (this may take a while)
>   Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
>   Download error: (11001, 'getaddrinfo
>   failed') -- Some packages may not be
>   found!
>
> No local packages or download links
>   found for fpconst Best match: None
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "setup.py", line 68, in ?
>       install_requires=[   File "D:\Python2.4\lib\distutils\core.py",
>   line 149, in setup
>       dist.run_commands()   File "D:\Python2.4\lib\distutils\dist.py",
>   line 946, in run_commands
>       self.run_command(cmd)   File "D:\Python2.4\lib\distutils\dist.py",
>   line 966, in run_command
>       cmd_obj.run()   File "D:\Python2.4\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py",
>   line 76, in run
>       self.do_egg_install()   File "D:\Python2.4\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py",
>   line 104,  in do_egg_install
>       cmd.run()   File "D:\Python2.4\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py",
>   line  211, in run
>       self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)   File
>   "D:\Python2.4\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py",
>   line  427, in easy_install
>       return self.install_item(None, spec, tmpdir, deps, True)   File
>   "D:\Python2.4\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py",
>   line  478, in install_item
>       self.process_distribution(spec, dist, deps)   File
>   "D:\Python2.4\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py",
>   line  518, in process_distribution
>       distros = WorkingSet([]).resolve(   File
>   "D:\Python2.4\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py",
>   line 563, in resolve
>       dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, self, installer)
>   File
>   "D:\Python2.4\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py",
>   line 799, in best_matc h
>       return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install   File "D:\Python2.4\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py",
>   line 811, in obtain
>       return installer(requirement)   File
>   "D:\Python2.4\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py",
>   line  434, in easy_install
>       self.local_index   File "D:\Python2.4\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py",
>   line 475, i n fetch_distribution
>       return dist.clone(location=self.download(dist.location,
>   tmpdir)) AttributeError: 'NoneType'
>   object has no attribute 'clone'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error:** *`No local packages or download links found`* ..

Go [here](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/) -> decompress the file -> open a **cmd** and *cd dir* to SOAPpy files -> type *python setup.py install* to run it.

Then run IDE to check it, by ***import*** SOAPpy.

Comment: Hi, I tried the same. During the SOAPpy installation, its still searching for fpconst in http://pypi.python.org/simple/fpconst/ eventhough fpconst is installed on the machine.